# How to pass a html object multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my problem is the following:

I have a `onClick` function. The function have a param with the current element object and a status code. The whole function should be redeclared at clicking the function.

onClick

```
<button onClick="test(1, this);">test</button>
```

Function

```
function test(status, obj) {

    if(status == 0)  $(obj).attr('onclick','test(1, '+ obj +')'); 
    else if(status == 1)  $(obj).attr('onclick','test(0, '+ obj +')');  
}
```

The problem is that the html element after the first click is not working. I will get the error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Note: This is just a dummy function. The questions is just about the general thing.

QUESTION:
Why can I not pass a the parameter `obj` to the function one more time?

The code is just a example of the problem. I know that there are several solutions for this. But I want to understand why it is not working.

It is also not working with `this`.

Comment: _“The whole function should be redeclared at clicking the function”_ - why, what do you actually want to _achieve_ by this?

Comment: If you are using jQuery already, then you should stay away from doing event handling via onclick attributes in the first place.

Comment: I just want to pass the html obj to the changed function. What I want is visible in the test function.

Comment: The pattern you're using is very far from ideal. It would make much more sense to have a single unobtrusive event handler whose logic is affected by a single state flag.

Comment: A single event is not a solution for my question.

Comment: _“A single event is not a solution for my question”_ - then include _why_ that is in your question. Make an effort, and actually properly describe what the actual _problem_ is that you are trying to solve here. Do that with your _words_, not code.

Comment: Please read my post. There is no achievement to reach. It is just a question I got into and have no idea why I can not pass a second time the html obj. I know that there are several solution for a problem like this.

Comment: So this question is a theoretical problem? In which case it's entirely moot as this is something you should never ever be doing.

Comment: Yes, it is  a theoritcal problem. I had a similar problem in my project, but solved it with data attributes. But I don't get into why it will not work with this solution in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why you would do such a thing but it can be easily achieved using plain javscript.

Furthermore you're passing the actual object  (obj) into the onclick whereas you should just use "this" because it will be evaluated later.

Solution:

```js
function test(status, obj){
  alert(status);
  if(status == 0){
   obj.setAttribute("onClick", "test(1,this);");
 }
 else if (status == 1){
   obj.setAttribute("onClick", "test(0,this);");
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="test(1,this);" >Click</button>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

The same is true for your jQuery answer:

```js
function test(status, obj) {
  alert(status);
  if(status == 0)  $(obj).attr('onclick','test(1, this)'); 
  else if(status == 1)  $(obj).attr('onclick','test(0,this)');  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="test(1,this);" >Click</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a design issue. Rather then changing the handler from one event to another you should change the handler logic.

```
<button onClick="handler(this)">


function handler(obj){
   if(!obj.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
      // this is the first time button got clicked
      obj.status = 0; // or whatever is the initial value
   }
   switch(obj.status){
     case 0: // do whatever the 0 case should do
            obj.status = 1;
            break;
     case 1: // do whatever the 1 case should do
            obj.status = 0;
            break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the event handle api instead of attr('onclick',...)

```
function test(status, obj) {
    if(status == 0) {
       $(obj).off('click').click(function() {
           test(1, obj);
        }); 
    } else if(status == 1) {
       $(obj).off('click').click(function() {
           test(0, obj);
        });
    } 
}
```